# setting up an if else statement to check for a querystring

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm looking to make an if else statement that does one action if it detects a query string and another action if there isn't one detected. My trouble is in the syntax, I haven't been able to find a good example.

I'm looking for something along the lines of:

```
if (requisition_id = null)

    do this action

else

    do this action
```

I'm basically looking for the syntax needed to identify the querystring, the rest of the code I've got ready for it.

Any help appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Noticing a lack of attempted code and question marks.

Comment: This question isn't that bad, is it?  It doesn't show much research effort, but it is very clear and quite possibly useful to someone else at some point.  As they say, 2 out of 3 ain't bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To read the value of a query argument, use the `QueryString` collection of the `Request` object. If it returns `null` for the query argument name, then it was not supplied in the URL.

```
string argname = Request.QueryString["argname"];
if (argname != null)
{
    // argname contains the argument value
}
else
{
    // No argument value was supplied
}
```